# Documenting package __init__ imports with Sphinx

Tags: python, pandas, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a Python package, felling which has a method:

```py
from felling.src.email import send_email
```

Following from how Pandas handles imports such as `pandas.DataFrame` in `felling.__init__.py` I have:

```py
# felling.__init__.py
from felling.src.email import send_email
```

Which allows someone to import `felling.src.email.send_email` by using:

```py
from felling import send_email
```

With this last import method being the main way I intend `send_email` to be imported. Nobody ever runs `from pandas.core.api import DataFrame` despite this being valid.

When documenting `felling` with Sphinx it documents `send_email` as `felling.src.email.send_email` not `felling.email`. I've read through Pandas docs and cannot figure how they get Sphinx to document `pandas.core.api.DataFrame` as `pandas.DataFrame`.

How can I do this?

#### Example `.py`

```py
# felling.src.email

def send_email(to:str, subject:str):
    """
    Send an email

    Parameters
    ----------
    to : str
        Who should receive the email
    subject : str
        What should the emails subject be
    """
    print(to)
    print(subject)
```

#### Example `.rst`

```
felling methods
===============

A package for logging

felling.src.email
------------------------

.. automodule:: felling.src.email
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

#### Felling's tree

```
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── resources
│   └── logger.json
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── compare_logs.py
│   ├── configure_felling.py
│   └── email.py
└── version.py
```

Comment: Can you include an example `.py` and `.rst` and are you using intersphinx?

Comment: I am not using intersphinx. I've added and example `.py` and `.rst` to the question, hope this helps

Comment: Have you tried `.. automodule:: felling.send_email`? It should work...

Comment: I have and I get:

```WARNING: autodoc: failed to import data 'send_email.subject' from module 'felling'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'felling.send_email'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import data 'send_email.to' from module 'felling'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'felling.send_email'
```
`import felling.send_email` fails as send_email is a function that belongs to felling and not a module

Comment: Well, if `felling.send_email` is a function try [.. autofunction:: felling.send_email](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) instead. Assuming `felling` is a module or package, you can also try `.. automodule:: felling` to see how it goes. (Btw, edit the question to include the error/warnings). If this is your package/module also include a simple [tree](https://web.csulb.edu/~murdock/tree.html) of the files and the `__init__.py` where you are changing the module names. Some info is lacking from the question at this point.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, if I had I must have implemented it wrong as that works! Thank you, sorry if this was a basic problem, I'm not that experienced with Sphinx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `__init__.py` file makes it possible that [qualified names](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name) for classes and functions don't correspond directly to how modules are organized as files. A good example is given in [this answer](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name).

The autodoc directives import your objects as you normally would in Python. The first argument of a directive should be the fully qualified name of the object it's importing, so any name the `__init__.py` changes to allow an import should also be usable as an argument to the directive.

> [Directives - autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directives)
>
> autodoc provides several directives that are versions of the usual py:module, py:class and so forth. On parsing time, they import the corresponding module and extract the docstring of the given objects, inserting them into the page source under a suitable py:module, py:class etc. directive.

This means, in the case of the question, you could use:

```
.. autofunction:: felling.send_email
```

or

```
.. automodule:: felling
```